# Cómo ordenar una tabla calculada empleada en una medida de manera descendente

Tags: powerbi, dax

Tengo una tabla con dos columnas, "Nombre cliente" e "Importe facturado". Necesito crear una medida que me devuelva una cadena de texto en la que se concatenen todos los importes facturados mayores al de cada línea y ordenados descendentemente.

Generé esta medida:

```
var t1=FILTER(ALL(Clientes),[Importe]>sum([Importe]))
return CONCATENATEX(t1,FORMAT([Importe],"Currency"),UNICHAR(10))
```

En cada línea me devuelve todos aquellos importes que son mayores que el importe de la propia línea concatenados con un salto de línea. El problema es que están desordenados. Me gustaría tenerlos ordenados de mayor a menos.

He intentado varias cosas con las fórmulas SUMMARIZE, RANKX, pero no me ha salido. Le he preguntado a GPT, pero no me ha soltado más que chorradas incongruentes.

En DAX Studio es muy fácil hacerlo gracias a la función ORDERBY, pero esta fórmula no existe en DAX de PBI.

¿Alguien puede orientarme por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguí solucionarlo. No sé si hay forma más rápida, pero al menos funciona correctamente.

Dejo el código por si os es de utilidad. Si alguien conoce un método mejor, que comente por favor.

```
 Mayores =
    VAR t1 =
        FILTER ( ALL ( Clientes ), [Importe] > SUM ( Clientes[Importe] ) )
    VAR t2 =
        ADDCOLUMNS ( t1, "Rango", RANKX ( t1, [Importe],, DESC ) )
    VAR t3 =
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
           GENERATESERIES ( 1, COALESCE ( COUNTROWS ( t2 ), 1 ) ),
           "Importe", SUMX ( FILTER ( t2, [Rango] = [Value] ), [Importe] )
        )
    RETURN
       CONCATENATEX ( t3, FORMAT ( [Importe], "Currency" ), UNICHAR ( 10 ) )
```